# Google Chrome Black Screen in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, google-chrome

I have an issue with the latest update of Google Chrome on my Xubuntu 14.04.

When I open a browser, it's webpage region is completely black, only toolbars are visible. When I try to resize or move browser's window it jumps to the bottom right corner of the screen and I can't get it out of there.

**The screenshot:**

[image: Google Chrome window with black region]

I've tried to re-install it, but it didn't help.

How do I fix it?

---

## UPDATE #1

I've installed the latest version of `chromium-browser` just to see how it will perform.

There is no black screen in it, but I still have the problem of moving/resizing it's window.

Comment: And what about lower versions?

Comment: @Mr.TK you mean to install previous version? I'm not sure how to do this properly. I've installed Chrome from official Google's deb-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this problem was related to the *Xinerama* and proprietary *NVIDIA* drivers.

The black screen disappeared as soon as I switched to **304.117** version of NVIDIA drivers. Although, incorrect positioning of the window is still present, but I can coupe with this until better solution emerge.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: [Arch Wiki Xinerama](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead#Xinerama) "Warning: As of August 2013, Xinerama is broken when using the proprietary NVIDIA driver from 319 upwards. Users wishing to use Xinerama with the NVIDIA driver should use the NVIDIA 313 driver, which works only with Linux kernels earlier than 3.10."

Comment: I have had precisely this problem. It remains unclear to me when (or if!) Xinerame (or the proprietary NVIDIA drivers) will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling GPU compositing on all pages  from the setting available on chrome://flags/ and see if it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there another way to change this flags? I can't change them from inside the browser itself for obvious reasons =)

Comment: Did you try reinstalling chrome again?

Comment: I just downloaded latest deb file from Google Chrome's website and re-installed it with GUI. Still no joy.

Comment: please can you post a screenshot here?

Comment: I've updated my question with the screenshot.

Comment: Click drop-down menu on top-right corner –> click “Settings” –> click “Show advanced settings…” on the bottom –> scroll to the bottom, and uncheck “Use hardware acceleration when available" Try using this

Comment: I can't access settings cause this interface is rendered the same way as a web-page does. It just black. Is there a way to do this using some config files for example?

Comment: You can try disabling your plugins.

Comment: Good idea. How do I do this?

Comment: Try opening an icognito window if u have your extensions disabled in icognito.

Comment: Or you can just right click on the plugin icons and click remove from chrome

Comment: Whats the status?

Comment: Incognito window has the same issue.

Comment: Try disabling GPU process from task manager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14645/discussion-between-ritik-and-slava-fomin-ii).